# How to obtain operation-version of the principle of equivalence from the property-version

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory

From this [link](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/principle+of+equivalence#general_definition)

> If $X$ is an $\infty$-groupoid, then a property $P$ of objects of $X$ is compatible with equivalence if, whenever $P(a)$ holds for an object $a$ of $X$ and $b$ is equivalent (as an object of $X$) to $a$, then $P(b)$ holds. Alternatively, an operation $f$ from objects of $X$ to objects of (another $\infty$-groupoid) $Y$ is compatible with equivalence if, whenever $a$ and $b$ are equivalent objects of $X$, $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ are equivalent (as objects of $Y$).

in the same link is written:

> The operation-version of the principle of equivalence gives the property-version if you think of a property as an operation taking values in the $\infty$-groupoid (in fact a $0$-groupoid, or set) of truth values. (The property-version also gives the operation-version, although that is a little more involved.)

Here is my question: how can you recast the operation-version of the principle of equivalence in the property-version?

Comment: Am I crazy or is the "principle of equivalence" not stated anywhere formally in this page? What principle do you want to recast in the language of properties, exactly?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi why do you say it is not stated formally?

Comment: Well I couldn't find a statement of the principle, just something in the "Idea" section. But the page is very long so I may have missed it. Where is the principle in question stated?

Comment: Basically *principle of equivalence*$equiv$*compatibility with equivalence.
Nonetheless I think I finally got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I finally got it.

For each operation $f$ defined between two (object-sets) of two $\infty$-groupoids $X$ and $Y$ and each object $a \in X$ we can define the property 
$$P_{f,a}(x) \equiv f(a) \sim f(x)$$
where $x \sim y$ stands for *$x$ is equivalent to $y$*.

Then the operation $f$ satisfies the principle of equivalence (i.e. is compatible with equivalence) if and only if for each $a \in X$ the property $P_{f,a}(x)$ is compatible with equivalence.

Indeed if $f$ is compatible with equivalence then for every $a \in X$ if $b,c \in X$ are such that $b \sim c$ then we have 
$$P_{f,a}(b) \equiv f(a) \sim f(b)\ ,$$
$$P_{f,a}(c) \equiv f(a) \sim f(c)$$
and 
$$f(b) \sim f(c)$$
hence, since $\sim$ is an equivalence relation, it follow
that $P_{f,a}(b) \iff P_{f,a}(c)$.

On the other hand if for each $a \in X$ the property $P_{f,a}(x)$ satisfies the principle of equivalence then for each pair $a,b \in X$ if $a \sim b$ we have that 
$$P_{f,a}(a) \equiv f(a) \sim f(a)$$
is clearly true and so 
$$P_{f,a}(b) \equiv f(a) \sim f(b)$$
must be true too.